# How to install a NPAPI plugin by running an installer or script in the background?

Tags: javascript, batch-file, npapi, firebreath

I want to install a NPAPI plugin as soon as my web page detects if the plugin is not there.

The installation or a batch script should be run in the background without asking the user.
But I think installation will require user permission, so running a batch file is preferable.

If I need to run a batch to register the plugin's dll from javascript, how can I do that?

Comment: Obviously a web page isn't allowed to install anything without asking the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.  If you find a way to do so anyway, please let us know so that the security vulnerability can be fixed.

If you could automatically run a script, installer, or batch file without the user's permission or knowledge that would be called a "virus". that's generally considered a bad thing...

You could look into Native Client, though it only works on Chrome; Native Client plugins can be installed without user intervention because they are sandboxed with limited access to the user's computer.

Comment: I have thought of doing it by detecting if the plugin has been installed using 'navigator.plugins' function. If not installed, I will  give a link to a MSI installer which will install the plugin (in case of Windows only)

Comment: That is what I do.  It does require user intervention, but when you think about it that's kinda a good thing.  Note that you'll need to do a navigator.plugins.refresh(false) in order to have it rescan for new plugins

Comment: Thanks for the **navigator.plugins.refresh** functionality